# Headphone and Speaker both works together in 12.10

Tags: sound, configuration, headphones, speakers

This is the most common problem. My headphone and speakers working at the same time. I need an option to switch between my headphone and speakers or at least mute speakers when I plug the headphone.

Card: HDA Intel   Chip: Realtek ALC268

I tried lots of solution for the past 2 days. Nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: What nonworking solutions did you try?

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal run alsamixer.   Once in alsamixer use the left and right arrows to navigate to the speaker or headphone and reduce the volumes appropriately.